# Refetching queries does not work - React Query

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-query

I'm trying to refetch some queries after one success but it's not working!

I used two ways to handle it by using `refetchQueries()` / `invalidateQueries()`

1- onSuccess callback

```
export const useMutateAcceptedOrder = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  return useMutation(
    ['AcceptedOrder'],
    (bodyQuery: AcceptedOrderProps) => acceptOrder(bodyQuery),
    {
      onSuccess: () => {
        console.log('success, refetch now!');
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getNewOrders']); // not work
        queryClient.refetchQueries(['getNewOrders']); // not work
      },
      onError: () => {
        console.error('err');
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getNewOrders']); // not work
      },
    },
  );
};
```

second way

```
 const {mutateAsync: onAcceptOrder, isLoading} = useMutateAcceptedOrder();
 const acceptOrder = async (orderId: string) => {
    const body = {
      device: 'iPhone',
      version: '1.0.0',
      location_lat: '10.10',
      location_lng: '10.10',
      orderId: orderId,
      os: Platform.OS,
      source: 'mobile',
      token: userInfo.token,
    };
    await onAcceptOrder(body);
    queryClient.refetchQueries(['getNewOrders']); // not work
    queryClient.invalidateQueries(['getActiveOrders']); // not work
    handleClosetModalPress();
  };
```

sample of query I wanted to refetch after the success

```
export const useNewOrders = (bodyQuery: {token: string | null}) => {
  console.log('token>>', bodyQuery.token);
  return useQuery(['getNewOrders'], () => getNewOrders(bodyQuery), 
  {
    enabled: bodyQuery.token != null,
  });
};
```

App.tsx

```
const App: React.FC<AppProps> = ({}) => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  if (__DEV__) {
    import('react-query-native-devtools').then(({addPlugin}) => {
      console.log('addPlugin');
      addPlugin({queryClient});
    });
  }

 
  useEffect(() => {
    RNBootSplash.hide({fade: true}); // fade
  }, []);


  return (
    <GestureHandlerRootView style={{flex: 1}}>
      <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
        <BottomSheetModalProvider>
          <AppContainer />
        </BottomSheetModalProvider>
      </QueryClientProvider>
    </GestureHandlerRootView>
  );
};

export default App;
```

--

**EDIT**

So after using the `react-query-native-devtools` Debug tool, I can't see any query in the first tab recorded in the debugger! Although the data fetched well.

So I guess that's why the refetch did not work in this case!

> Any query in the first tab I can't refetch it again

**Steps to reproduce:**

- open App - Active Tab (first tab)
- check the status of the queries
- nothing recorded in the debugger
- Navigate to any other screen/tab
- Check the status of queries

all screen queries recorded in the debugger

Comment: Read the docs please. https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/invalidations-from-mutations You need to provide a queryKey property for invalidateQueries.

Comment: @Binit it's already exist `['getActiveOrders']`

Comment: The docs use it like these though ```queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: ['todos'] })```. whereas you're just passing them ```queryClient.refetchQueries(['getNewOrders']);```

Comment: @Binit same thing not works

Comment: What error does it show? Try to do it without creating any extra custom hooks first. Start with a clean slate of react query. And go through the docs for information. It seems you're also not using query keys properly  as shown in docs https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/guides/query-keys. Are you following a tutorial or something?

Comment: @OliverD I was facing the same issue just now - did you try using `queryClient.invalidateQueries({queryKey: ['getNewOrders']})`? I just had to call it this way, `refetchQueries` wasn't even required

Comment: @Myzel394 yes i tried this way, but the same issue still :(

Answer (score 7):

Per https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-fa-qs#2-the-queryclient-is-not-stable:

> If you move the client creation into the App component, and your component re-renders for some other reason (e.g. a route change), your cache will be thrown away:

Need to init `queryClient` like that:

`const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient())`

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and haven't been able to find a proper solution for this, however I have found a hacky workaround. You just call your refetch function or invalidate queries inside a setTimeout.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively old question, but I ran into the same problem.   I ended up solving my problem in a few ways:

#1 I changed my update API endpoints so that after modifying a record, it sends the whole new record back, and I end up doing `queryClient.setQueryData` to update the local cache.

#2 Even though `queryClient.invalidateQueries` is plural, I switched everything to singular invalidations per query key.

#3 Grepped my code base to ensure there is only 1 instance of `new QueryClient` and everywhere else is using `useQueryClient`

#4 Last and perhaps least, I added `.then()` to `invalidateQueries` just in case the async code was somehow never being executed.

Note https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/query-invalidation#query-matching-with-invalidatequeries The invalidate query call only seems to work if I added the mentioned `fetchType` param.

Here is the documentation for https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetqueriesdata

Below is a full example of what I did above.

```js
const _updateCharacter = useMutation<Character, Error, Character>({
        mutationFn: (character: Character) => api.update_character(character),
        onSuccess: (updated_character) => {
            queryClient.setQueryData(
                ['book', activeBook.id, 'character', updated_character.id],
                () => updated_character
            )

            queryClient
                .invalidateQueries({
                    queryKey: ['book', activeBook.id, 'characters'],
                    exact: true,
                    refetchType: 'active'
                })
                .then()
        },
        onError: (error) => {
            console.log(error)
        }
    })
```

This is for a detailed book inventory management system.   The goal is to update the details for a specific character BUT, in addition, update a list of all characters to reflect a name change, note word count, and the last updated field.

Not relevant, but every Character record has an internal id primary key and an exposed `snowflake` unique identifier, so that's why I can get away with just passing the record to the API without its associated book.

I hope this helps someone else and saves them from slowly losing their mind as nothing seems to work.